# Matlab function calling basic

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and now learning the basic grammar.

I've written the file GetBin.m:

```
function res = GetBin(num_bin, bin, val)
if val >= bin(num_bin - 1)
    res = num_bin;
else
    for i = (num_bin - 1) : 1
        if val < bin(i)
            res = i;
        end
    end
end
```

and I call it with:

```
num_bin = 5;
bin = [48.4,96.8,145.2,193.6]; % bin stands for the intermediate borders, so there are 5 bins
fea_val = GetBin(num_bin,bin,fea(1,1)) % fea is a pre-defined 280x4096 matrix
```

It returns error:

```
Error in GetBin (line 2)
if val >= bin(num_bin - 1)

Output argument "res" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"/Users/mac/Documents/MATLAB/GetBin.m>GetBin".
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that every possible path through your code assigns a value to `res`.

In your case, it looks like that's not the case, because you have a loop:

```
for i = (num_bins-1) : 1
    ...
end
```

That loop will never iterate (so it will never assign a value to `res`).  You need to explicitly specify that it's a decrementing loop:

```
for i = (num_bins-1) : -1 : 1
    ...
end
```

For more info, see the documentation on the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = (num_bin - 1) : -1 : 1
```